# Problem with Nvidia GeForce 820m driver Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a laptop Dell Inspiron-3542 with Nvidia GeForce 820m & an Intel HD 4400 (I don't want to use it).

I want to use only Nvidia with the last updated driver supported by GeForce 820m.

When I use `nvidia-340` it works, not very well but it works like:
[image]

- The problem with `nvidia-340` that it is outdated & I can't use it to play 3d games and does not support DXVK & Vulkan.
  When I try to open Lutris I got this:

[image]

The problem is that I can't use a driver more updated than 340.
Any other driver I have tried to install it doesn't work, and the system returns to Intel HD instead of Nvidia.
I have tried to add repositories from:
[https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)
and I got drivers like :
[image]

If I install 450 or 450 the system returns to HD graphic
If I check drivers list I got:

[image]

If i try to install other version directly like 390, it is refused from the system.
I got this result:

[image]

I have read a lot of topics & saw many videos but haven't found a solution.
Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Comment: Try installing from the standard repos nvidia-driver-390

Comment: I got this error : https://www10.0zz0.com/2020/10/03/02/705410148.png   ... If i remove nvidia completly & install it, i got errors in other steps

Comment: A quick scan of the Nvidia site for your hardware shows the 391 driver -- do you have any information that a later driver works?  If not, stick with the 390.  Clean out all Nvidia packages you now have and install the nvidia-driver-390

Comment: I have installed 390.138 with succes, and  i see that it work better than 340 ;  https://www3.0zz0.com/2020/10/03/23/633491014.png                                                          But the problem not solved, it is always outdated, see : https://www3.0zz0.com/2020/10/03/23/678260103.png       If i try to install a more updated driver i got a message error that the last update supported by my system is 390 ..

Comment: I see nmath found that the 430 driver should be supported too at https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/149138/en-us

Comment: I got these errors : https://www9.0zz0.com/2020/10/04/20/321755334.png       then     https://www9.0zz0.com/2020/10/04/20/374338707.png    then   https://www9.0zz0.com/2020/10/04/20/901985198.png

Comment: Lots of current discussions about this on various questions here -- Nvidia does claim 430 driver supports the 820m, but seems 390 is the highest one people have gotten to work in Ubuntu.

Comment: I see @ubfan1 , i thank you very much for your help, i am waiting for solution.

Answer (score 1):

Install the package `nvidia-384` and you'll get the 390. As its description (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/nvidia-384) says, the 384 is a "transitional package for nvidia-driver-390".

I too have the 820M, and on a very similar laptop, the Inspiron 3442.