# Nvidia Geforce 820M GPU problem on mainly ubuntu-based distros

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, amd-graphics, bumblebee

Ok, I really love linux but I REALLY DETEST the fact that it is awful with GPUs.

Over the last couple of weeks I have tried fedora, kubuntu, kde neon, zorin os, and manjaro and NONE of then could utilize my nvidia graphics card.

I have literally tried everything.

I did a standard nvidia install: 'sudo apt install nvidia-xxx (I think I did 470)'

I think I also tried: 'sudo apt install nvidia-driver-xxx'

I added this ppa: 'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa'

Then I installed the drivers.

I also did this: 'sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall'
Got nothing (no message was shown)

I went into additional drivers but nothing was there.

I tried bumblebee but there this error saying it can't access secondary GPU and also if it did work I don't want to constantly have a terminal open and run my apps through there.

I used manjaro and installed: 'video-driver-390xx' (I think it was this) but when  I restarted my laptop there this black screen that lasted for millennia. Then I force shut down my laptop and started it again but the OS wouldn't move past this message:
'[ OK ] Started CUPS calculator' or something like this. And now, it's back to the black screen

I have an ASUS X555LDB that utilizes this absurd hybrid technology thing. My Nvidia graphics card is a Geforce 820M, the other one is Mesa Intel HD Graphics 5500 (which is the one that the os uses no matter what). Can someone please help me before I go insane?

Comment: Did you disable Secure Boot in the BIOS?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.    *You mention many OSes, but only one is actually on-topic for this site - maybe you should ask at SE Unix & Linux, or are you asking about an on-topic OS for this site?*

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you try?

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279567/problem-with-nvidia-geforce-820m-driver-ubuntu-20-04 Also see this. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279769/geforce-820m-black-screen-after-installing-legacy-drivers NVidia seems to have abandoned support for this GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, nvidia driver support on especially Ubuntu is quite good. The Geforce 820M however is quite a strange GPU. There exists multiple devices under the name of 820M. One of them is using a GF117 chip which is based on the Fermi architecture. There however also seems to be a variant that is based on the Kepler architecture using a GK107 chip which is called GTX 820M. The X555LDB seems to be using the older GF117 chip which is not supported by the latest nvidia drivers anymore (it was dropped around 2018). The latest driver that supports Fermi is either 430.40 or 390.144. You might have more luck switching to the open-source driver ("nouveau") which should support Fermi quite well.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for my Nividia Geforce 820M with the GF117 chip :

https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-nvidia-driver-is-not-detected-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts/

In short:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440
```

The installation was smooth, the driver is up and running. But I have no long term experience yet.